# Issue converting SQL query to Hibernate query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, join, hql

I am a Hibernate newbie and I need to convert my SQL query to Hibernate format:

```
SELECT pr.id as id,
        pr.name as name,
        pr.brand as brand,
        pr.age as age,
        pi.image_url as imageUrl
    FROM product pr
        JOIN product_image pi ON
            (pr.id=pi.id and pi.image_url IN 
                (SELECT t0.image_url
                    FROM product_image AS t0
                        LEFT JOIN product_image AS t1 ON
                            (t0.id = t1.id AND
                                t1.image_order > t0.image_order)
                                    WHERE t0.image_url IS NOT NULL))
```

This query is working and getting the desired output, but I have to convert it to `Hibernate` format.

I have created a `Product` and `ProductImage` entity class, there is a `Set` of `ProductImage` in the `Product` class, and I am using `fetchType.LAZY`. I want to display one image for each product and for that, I am fetching the image with the highest: `preference(image_order)`. Please help me convert my query to Hibernate format. Thanks in advance

My Entity classes:

---

### Product:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="product")
public class Product  implements java.io.Serializable {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String brand;
    private String snippet;
    private Set<ProductDetail> productDetails = new HashSet<>(0);
    private Set<ProductImage> productImages = new HashSet<>(0);
    //constructors, setters and getters
}
```

---

### ProductImage:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="product_image")
public class ProductImage  implements java.io.Serializable {
    private Integer id;
    private Product product;
    private String imageUrl;
    private Integer imageOrder;
    //constructors setters and getters
}
```

---

### ProductDetail:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="product_detail")
public class ProductDetail  implements java.io.Serializable {
    private Integer id;
    private Product product;
    private String property;
    private String value;
    //constructors ,getters and setters
}
```

Comment: I think you need to show us your entity classes.

Comment: Please check the entity classes

Comment: Do you have code that is generating an error, throwing an exception, that will not run, or that produces an incorrect result? Or is it that you are stuck figuring out how to move forward because you are unfamiliar with Hibernate?

Comment: I need help to move forward . I dont know how to convert it to hibernate without inner queries as it take more time

Comment: you can run the query itself and get the data. There is an option in hibernate to execute SQL query

Comment: yes. createSQLQuery() can be used. But, I need to convert it to HQL format. Also have to avoid inner queries to improve performance and also to learn HQL